# Is there any specific rules concerning about mysql alias?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, alias

Recently, I was learning MySQL following this particular guide. https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/

Databases and tables were set up as directed in the tutorial. While running the following code, it results in a syntax error

```html
SELECT 
    m.member_id, 
    m.name member, 
    c.committee_id, 
    c.name committee
FROM
    members m
INNER JOIN committees c 
 ON c.name = m.name;

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ', 
    c.committee_id, 
    c.name committee
FROM
    members m
INNER JOIN commi' at line 3
```

With a few experiments, this syntax error can be fixed by changing the alias member to something else or by adding quotes around it. However, I am unclear to how and why these solutions work. 
PS: The version of MySQL I am using is Ver 8.0.19.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`member` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html), so you must encapsulate the mmmber with single quotes

```
SELECT 
    m.member_id, 
    m.name 'member', 
    c.committee_id, 
    c.name committee
FROM
    members m
INNER JOIN committees c 
    ON c.name = m.name;
```

check also [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

`member` is [a reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) on some specific MySQL versions: it became reserved in version 8.0.17, then it seems like MySQL designers changed their mind and reversed that in version 8.0.19.

So you need to either change the alias name (which I would recommend), or surround it with backticks: this turns it to a quoted identifier, which never clash with reserved words, as [explained in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html):

> An identifier may be quoted or unquoted. If an identifier contains special characters or is a reserved word, you must quote it whenever you refer to it.

And, further:

> The identifier quote character is the backtick (`)